# Sort by specific custom type in angular

Tags: angular, sorting

I have a list of elements which one of the property is type, adn its values: { footprint, platform, roving }
I am trying to sort the list following the next criteria:
platform > footprint > roving

Since alphbetical order footprint is before platform, sorting by the field is not working as expected and I don't know exactly how to implement a custom sort callback to do it.
I am using https://vadimdez.github.io/ngx-order-pipe/ module and here is my try:

## template

```
...
 <tr *ngFor="let platform of platforms | orderBy: order: false: true: sortCriteria; let i = index;">
...
...
```

## component

```
...
order: string[] = ['type', 'name'];
...
  sortCriteria(itemA, itemB) {
    if (itemA.type == 'platform') return 1;
    if (itemB.type == 'platform') return -1;
    if ((itemA.type == 'footprint') && (itemB.type == 'roving')) return 1
    if (itemA.type == 'roving') return -1
  }    
...
```

I will appreciate some ideas to get this sort works as expected.

Comment: If you get the collection 'platforms' from a server you should sort it in the server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create an 'order array' and fill it with correct order that do you want to use. Then use simple code:

```js
let typesOrder = ['platform', 'footprint', 'roving'];

sortCriteria(itemA, itemB) {
    return typesOrder.indexOf(itemA.type) < typesOrder.indexOf(itemB.type);
}
```